# How can I display sources of a dependent jarfile in eclipse maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

After I downloaded sources and JavaDocs of a jarfile which is a dependency to my project in eclipse, how can I **browse** or **display** its source codes?

and my second question: Is it possible to **edit and build** them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only way to display and browse the jarfile's source coude is under the *.m2/repository* directory.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project , click on Maven -- > cick on download java doc and download source.

for your second question, you can not change/edit the source and build

Comment: I said clearly that I have downloaded sources and JavaDocs.